# Unable to load and run bootstrap.js in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, asynchronous

For a very specific use case (some kind of demo of parts of a full-page application inside an other Web-App) I need to load content from an html page into an iframe, apply css an run js.

The loaded content uses bootstrap elements with js. Since there are many different examples that are loaded, I do not want to manually add the bootstrap js and the required css to each loaded html snippet manually (which does work) but instead add it per js once the html is loaded into the iframe.

What I do is the following: After making sure that the DOM of the html is completely loaded into the iframe I add the css and necessary js as follows:

```
$('#'+index+'-iframe-example').contents().find("head").append(
  '<link href="/app/static/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'
);
$('#'+index+'-iframe-example').contents().find("body").append(
  '<script src="/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>'
);
$('#'+index+'-iframe-example').contents().find("body").append(
  '<script src="/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>'
);
```

Now the problem: The css is properly loaded and the content of the iframe is rendered correctly. The js is also loaded and executed, but the elements in the iframe do not react as they should. If add the js manually the the html snippets, it works.

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Nope, but If I enter something like console.log("hello Bootstrap"); in the first line of bootstrap.js I see, that this line is effectively executed. It is just not applied on the DOM of the iframe (I see, that the elements that should react to some action don't). If I add the js directly in the dom of the iframe, everything works as expected

Comment: Can you try assigning a click event to the iframe body and see if that works? Try getting jquery var inside the iframe. Like `$('iframe').get(0).contentWindow.$`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. If I add the line directly inside the iframe, it does not work, since the iframe is rendered before jquery is added from outside. If I add the line just after I add jquery, something funny happens: It is executed and the jquery logic is applied, but only on elements outside the iframe. So the line: <script>$("body").html("test")</script>, would replace the html of the whole body of the page with "test" and not just the part of the iframe. $("iframe").html("test") does not have any affect.

Comment: to change the iframe content, try this `$('iframe').contents().find('body').html('test')` .